# Pointers program

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int main()
{
    static int a[2][2] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int i, j;
    static int *p[] = {(int*)a, (int*)a+1, (int*)a+2};
    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<2; j++)
        {
            printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", *(*(p+i)+j), *(*(j+p)+i),
            *(*(i+p)+j), *(*(p+j)+i));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code the output is:

```
1, 1, 1, 1  
2, 2, 2, 2  
2, 2, 2, 2  
3, 3, 3, 3
```

Can someone please explain how this code works?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) to run your program step by step, displaying the relevant variables inside the debugger.

Comment: Are you sure you want to initialize `p` like you do? Maybe `(int*)a+1` should be `a[1]` ?

Comment: the op asked for explanation please don't neglect that

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this code. Are you not getting it. Have you tried some intermediate prints?

Comment: @TusharGupta As per First comment OP can look all variable in inside debugger. you can try to explain OP.

Comment: That was an interview question.So, no changes in the question and the code works perfectly. I just want explanation of each step that how pointers works.

Comment: @user3482643 You can play with [this code](http://ideone.com/gPfWRR) and (click on fork and) add more prints to understand what exactly is going on. If you don't understand something specific, feel free to ask. As starter, I would ask interviewer to prefer `static int a[2][2] = { {1, 2}, {3, 4} };` (notice extra pair of braces), remove unnecessary casts and avoid things like `a+1` etc.

Comment: @mohit jain what will be the values in*p[]?

Comment: @Shashank Because (int *) couples tighter than `+`, it would contain address of 0th, 1st and second element of array. (If the behaviour is well defined). Notice that `(int *)a+1` is not same as `(int *)(a+1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The four pointer operations in the printf:

```
*(*(p+i)+j)
*(*(j+p)+i)
*(*(i+p)+j)
*(*(p+j)+i)
```

Evaluate to the following:

```
*(*(p+i)+j) -> *(p[i]+j) 
*(*(j+p)+i) -> *(p[j]+i)
*(*(i+p)+j) -> *(i[p]+j) 
*(*(p+j)+i) -> *(j[p]+i)
```

`p[n]` is the same as `n[p]` as the pointer logic (as seen above) is commutitive around `+`.
see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-c-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a) for more details.

So there are really only two statements:

```
*(p[i]+j) 
*(p[j]+i)
```

Of course, this is just `p` + offset `[x]` + `offset`.  So really, it is only one statement:

```
*p[i+j]
```

Which is of course, the value stored in the `p` array at offset `i+j`.

Because of the nested loops, the values of i and j are as follows:

```
i j  i+j
0,0   0
0,1   1
1,0   1
1,1   2
```

So it prints in turn, the values in each location of `p` (`1`,`2`, `2`and`3`) four times.